# Use Jackson JSON processor without using annotations

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have a package which just includes and xsd file to generate (via JAXB) shared classes which are relevant for our server and client applications. So these classes contain XML annotations.

One client is an Android App. I also want to use these classes here for JSON deserialization because I communicate with a REST service which delivers JSON (with Jersey/[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)).

I try to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (version 1.7.2) on the Android like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper = mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS,
                false);
mapper = mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS,
                false);
FooBar someObject = (FooBar) mapper.readValue(jsonString, FooBar.class);
```

I though configure the MAPPER should avoid using annotations but I still get

```
02-07 09:30:18.631: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
02-07 09:30:18.631: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
02-07 09:30:18.631: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveClassAnnotations(AnnotatedClass.java:292)
02-07 09:30:18.631: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.construct(AnnotatedClass.java:139)
```

Who knows the trick to stop Jackson from resolving annotations.

Thanks
  Klaus

Comment: I have found Gson to be much easier to use and it will do automatic instantiation of POJO objects for direct conversion of JSON to objects.

Comment: Jackson can do full JSON->POJO->JSON data bindings trivially easily as well. So in what way would Gson be any easier to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current investigations lead to these results:

The usage of the `DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS` property (set to false)  will cause the JACKSON `DeserializerConfig` class to use a `NopAnnotationIntrospector`. Annotations of a class will then be resolved using this `NopAnnotationIntrospector`. The `NopAnnotationIntrospector` will return `false` on each `isHandled` request for any annotation on a class - and in fact will not use this annotation in further processing.

So - the system still "inspects" the annotations - which have to be on the Classpath in this case. As Android does not provide any jaxb-api annotations this leads to the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I expected `USE_ANNOTATIONS = false` would bring JACKSON to totally ignore any annotations - but unfortunately it does not. I will now use the Jackson Streaming API to parse the JSON string instead of using JACKSON Data Binding capabilities.

Comment: This makes sense, if the issue is that bean types you are using have JAXB annotations. Jackson itself (core, mapper) does not reference JAXB annotation types; only "jackson-xc" does (which has JAXB aware annotation introspector). But this is an interesting issue: I did not realize that simple access of annotations would be problematic -- after all, annotations are included directly in bytecode, and I expected issues to come up during class loading. But maybe I am wrong, and it only becomes problem when trying to read annotations? If so, maybe this would be an RFE for Jackson?

Comment: @StaxMan The annotations cause no problem if the are not in the classpath unless the get used (inspected). A Jackson change request NOT to inspect annotations in case of USE_ANNOTATIONS=false would be nice. I have no account to their system - and hesitate to create one just for this purpose.

Comment: Ok; I can add this one for you. It is interesting that JVM (or JDK) actually load annotations "on-demand" -- I assume it causes issue if any annotations are checked. I just assumed they would be eagerly loaded immediately, since doing it lazily can cause bit more obscure problems, but at the same time it can help in some cases.

Comment: Done, see [http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-487]. Btw, it's perfectly fine to submit suggestions; project can always choose what to work on etc, but they definitely do want to hear about issues, improvement ideas.

Comment: @StaxMan Thanks a lot! As I use JAXB annotated Classes in a context where these annotations are not provided it will definitely help me (and others) a lot. I checked "Type Loading" of the JVM and I learned :A type must appear to be loaded only when needed.  (http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2248831/Java-Class-Loading-The-Basics.htm). So I think its ok to use these JAXB annotated classes if I am sure no one will inspect the annotations.

Comment: Hmmh. Odd -- I actually can not reproduce this on regular JVM (1.6); if I do not include annotation types, I get no error, I just see no annotations. This from a stand-alone test.

Comment: Maybe you have to define a TestAnnotation (in a seperate library) which you use on a test object for marshalling/unmarshalling. When running the test the TestAnnotation must not be on the classpath. I suppose this test is hard to setup....

Comment: Wow, Jackson change already done. Looking forward for version 1.8.0

Comment: Yeah: wrt testing, that was done, but on J2SE JVM there is still no exception, even when I forcibly delete annotation class: annotations are just not seen. I guess Dalvik (or its SDK) just does not have as robust handling.

Comment: What do we need to do to fix this issue on Android ?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, Jackson trunk (pre-1.8.0) has code changes that will try to fully disable annotation processing; and theoretically this should solve the issue. 
One unfortunate thing is that this problem does NOT occur on regular J2SE JVM, but only on Android; so fix needs to be verified on Android. So it would be good to have an Android developer verify whether fix fully address the issue (if not, more work is needed).