# Stop Gson from introspecting class annotations

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I try to use [Gson](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home) on Android to marshall/unmarshall JAXB annotated classes.

The JAXB (XML) annotations are not provided on the Android device, thus the JSON library MUST not inspect annotations - otherwise we run into `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`.

I have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919996/use-jackson-json-processor-without-using-annotations) using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) but that seems to be [fixed](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-487) (thanks to StaxMan). As I do not know when the fix will be released I thought Gson would be an alternative, because of this documentation statement:

```
There is no need to use any annotations to indicate a field is to be included 
for serialization and deserialization. All fields in the current class (and 
from all super classes) are included by default.
```

Unfortunately I nevertheless run into this problem:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:196)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:199)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.google.gson.FieldAttributes.getAnnotations(FieldAttributes.java:159)
```

Is there a way to turn of Annotation inspection in Gson?

Thanks
  Klaus

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue since then?

Comment: @resus No, but I have not pursued the issue and therefore can't say something about the current status.

Answer (score 1):

[xStream has some JSON support built in](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html), maybe you should try that and see what the result is.

Comment: The latest news on the homepage is from 'Dec 6, 2008' and you do not know if my problem will be resolved with this library. Thanks for the hint to this library but I suppose I won't give it a try.

Comment: The [user-list](http://xstream.codehaus.org/list-user.html) is still active, with the lead developer responding to queries on it. And if you look at the [tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/XSTR?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:changelog-panel) the library is in maintenence mode

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's always good to have choices.